# About a blocking synchronized collection

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

Directly from this [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection%28java.util.Collection%29) ie `Collections.synchronizedCollection(Collection)`:

> The returned collection does not pass the hashCode and equals
>   operations through to the backing collection, but relies on Object's
>   equals and hashCode methods. This is necessary to preserve the
>   contracts of these operations in the case that the backing collection
>   is a set or a list.

Does it mean if I have my overridden methods `equals` and `hashCode`, those overridden methods won't be taken into account? If yes, why? it is quite misleading...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that `equals()` simply delegated to the backing collection, and suppose that this backing collection is the ArrayList `list`.

You would then have

```
Collections.synchronizedCollection(list).equals(list) == true
```

because it would be implemented by delegating to `list.equals(list)`.

But you would have

```
list.equals(Collections.synchronizedCollection(list)) == false
```

because lists can't be equal to collections that are not lists, and `Collections.synchronizedCollection(list)` is not a List.

This would severely break the contract of `Object.equals()`. If you want to preserve equality, use `Collections.synchronizedList()` to synchronize a List, and `Collections.synchronizedSet()` to synchronize a Set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.  It uses `equals` and `hashCode` method of `java.lang.Object` and hence, your implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` for your own class which you are putting in the collection will not be called to establish whether two such synchronized collections are equal or not.

You can see the code of `SynchronizedCollection` class here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.SynchronizedCollection

The reason it is like this is that the `SynchronizedCollection` is not aware of actual type of collection which it is wrappeing and hence cannot meaningfully perform `equals` method (or `hashCode` computation).  You can imagine this:  Two sets are equals if both have same elements (ordering does not matter), whereas two lists are equal if they have exactly same set of elements and in the same order.